# I could install Android Things in Qualcomm Snapdragon SoM

Tags: android-things

> Hi
>   I could install Android Things in any processor? Qualcomm Snapdragon System-on-a-Module For example?
>   Thank you

Comment: can u explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

At the moment [only the Dev boards are supported](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms), so I'm afraid not.
That is likely to change once it's out of developer preview.